# What is better approach to handle mobile elements in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a mobile version of some large site and the elements orders and content are very different. So i can add elements into HTML and set display: none, on desktop, with specific styles for mobile devices, or i can add new elements in JS, if i crate new elements i can easily make very light mobile version and add elements for desktop, but if i make large HTML for mobile and desktop versions it may be not to good as well. So what is the right way of doing this.

EDIT: there is a huge difference in layout, so i need to add many elements in html or JS, and i am asking about better way. I know how to handle it, but what is a better approach and why? There may be some other way of handling this situation, so tell me if you know.

P.S.
I know that this question must be answered before, but its hard to find answers to this kind of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the layout difference is not very huge then you can use the mobile friendly(Responsive) frameworks. But as you say that the "*content are very different*" which means you shall have to go with different DOM altogether or just a different CSS based on the complexity of the view.

Furthermore as you said you can have two parallel views with common content which are shown or hidden based on the media query. But then you have to deal with the problem of multiple events, redundant code, and different resolutions of the mobile too. So the choice is yours.

**Update:-** So if the differences in the mobile and desktop view are too big a list, then it inherently begs for two different views(pages). I'd go with loading a blank landing page first and then detecting whether the browser is mobile or not, and then redirecting with javascript. If you are using jQuery, something like ..

```
$( document ).ready(function() {      
    var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");

    if (isMobile.matches) {
        //Conditional script here
    }
 });
```

While also giving the user an option to change view if they think so.

Also I would further improvise by using ajax to load the respective view into the DOM instead of redirecting, which I am already implementing in my current apps and lets say the end users are happy :)

And lastly, there's no such thing as "right way" that works for all scenarios, you have to weigh your options and decide.

Comment: Is there some way of handling the differences between mobile and desktop version, if the design is not responsive, but must be adaptive, is there some patterns or ideas that somehow helps in performance. Its not really critical thing to do it, i am just interested in "right way".

Comment: @ZoltanKurtyak Updated answer.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Is there some way of html import without redirect? Or redirect don't really effects the loading speed?

Comment: Redirect can be instantaneous without the user even noticing, also If you are using `jQuery`  you can use `.load()` method of `jQuery` to load a whole page with all of **its** javascripts, css and rest of the objects using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If Mobile and Desktop has minor changes you can use display none.
You can use CSS framework like Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use bootstrap for mobile friendly websites as it will be much easier to handle the most of the html elements 
Or the different approach is to use Elements which can be hide in desktop or mobile as per required & use media queries to handle it

Answer (score 0):

To make responsive css use `@media` its stand for media query and as per you asked you need new element in mobile then instead hiding element and showing to mobile only use [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)